# Session variables intermittent PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a website and teach myself at the same time. I have implemented a database connection to allow users to register and sign in/out of the website but for some reason the session variables don't appear to be accessible from one specific page.

I have got the following php code on 2 pages that are in the same directory but the session vars are only accessible from one of the pages? Can anyone suggest what might be causing this and how this can be resolved?

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo "A";}
echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

The initialisation of the username is done here:

```
if (password_verify($password, $row["password"])) { 
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['userType'] = $row["userType"];
                header("location: ../index.php");
            }
```

Comment: Enable debugging at the top of the page: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`, and then run the script again. Post back if there are any errors. My guess is you have whitespace before the `<?php`

Comment: Do you have initialized $_SESSION['username'] ?

Comment: @FrankerZ I have added your suggestion and nothing is showing on the page. But still no echo.

Comment: @Nick Yes, it is initialised when the user signs in; and is accessible from other pages

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I have edited the question to include, again this is working on other pages so it should be ok?

Comment: So just to exclude some possibilities, have you checked that `password_verify($password, $row["password"]))` evaluated as true? :-)

Comment: @PhilippMaurer yes, on successful login the user is routed to the homepage, which is happening. The else just leaves them on the login page with an error

Comment: What is your php version? have you tried [session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) on the page you set your values to your session, right before the `header("location: ../index.php");`?

Comment: @a.norman Add `exit;` on the next line after `header(...);`

Comment: @a.norman One tip I can give you is that you should not throw a `session_start();` inside an `if` conditional. Put it in a config-type file and always include it at the top of every page, you will help yourself out. You never have to wonder if the session maybe didn't initialize or not. If you always have it started you just manage what is assigned to it and removed from it.

Comment: Like Rasclat said, use session_start() on the top of page and in if `if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && trim($_SESSION['name'] !== ''))`

Comment: @Cemal using 5.5, also tried adding session_write_close() but still not appearing on that page. It's odd because there are about 6 or so pages all of which work bar this one, but even if I copy the entire contents of a working page to the non working page it doesn't work

Comment: Is the page on the exact same domain? *foo.domain.com* **!=** *domain.com*

Comment: @Cemal yes, although just tried on IE and it works, could chrome be different somehow?

Comment: Hmm.. might be an issue with the cookies

Comment: I tried to remove extensions to see if that helped but it didn't, how could I test if it was cookies? I tried deleting all cookies and browsing data last night but that didn't fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

In my navigation bar I was using a full URL instead of a relative link, this was causing a new session ID to be created and hence the session data was lost. Changing the nav bar to use relative paths meant the data wasn't lost